# paragraph padding pushes away absolutely positioned heading

Tags: html, css, padding, absolute

Here I have been trying horizontally align h3 inside div.It all worked great but when I try adding padding to the p element it affects h3 what is absolutely positioned element and as I understood should not affect other elements nor be affected by others. So how come p padding affects it?
Here is link http://jsbin.com/yigakubijovo/1/edit

Comment: Probably because the padding increased the sizeof the div which affects the value of the `top:25%`.

Comment: Your heading is absolutely positioned on a relative value. You need to specify a pixel value. Or you could use the `top` rule like this `p{position: relative; top: 40px;}` even though it does not fit your design, it might work on your prod

Comment: guys I was trying to achieve this:http://jsbin.com/yigakubijovo/6/edit so basically vertically  align h3 inside top div border and add padding between h3 and p without affecting h3 so just pushing p down

Comment: When setting  top property  does it relate to the container  height and since adding padding to the p element increase container height could that be reason of why p padding affects h3 position?

Answer (score 0):

Reset the property "top" in the H3 for:

```
h3{
position:absolute;
left:25%;
right:25%;
background:red;
top:0;
}
```